# glGetObjectParameteriv not in GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew

In GLEW, it's only allowing me to use `glGetObjectParameterivARB` and not `glGetObjectParameteriv`. Why isn't `glGetObjectParameteriv` available in GLEW?

Answer (score 4):

Because that function doesn't exist, is part of the old ARB extensions for shader, but when GLSL moved to Core OpenGL, the API was changed a bit and this function was split into several others. You might want to look at:

- glGetShader
- glGetProgram
- glGetShaderInfoLog
- glGetProgramInfoLog